# ASP.NET Core System.TypeLoadException DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions error

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to Asp.Net Core. While creating a simple MVC project I got following error.

> System.TypeLoadException Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddOptions(IServiceCollection
>   services) at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection
>   services, Action setupAction) at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection
>   services, Action setupAction) at
>   POC.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException 
>   Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(object
>   instance, IServiceCollection exportServices) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Following is my Project.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Following is my Startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace POC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc( m=> 
            m.MapRoute(
                name:"Default",
                template:"{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults:new { controller="Home", action="index"}
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

I do get the error at the `service.AddMvc()` line in startup.cs file.
Please do suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this dependency for MVC in *project.json*:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
```

instead of these?

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

It's possible that using `AspNetCore` with `AspNet` for your MVC dependencies leads to conflicts.